# PHP Copy works, but rename does not

Tags: php, copy, rename

Today I was alerted to an error that started showing up in my company's system on august 30, 2019.

It is old school PHP and the warning is this (servername masked):

```
Warning: rename(\\gs-nkpg-raster\RASTER_IN\PROPRIUS\UT-MAPP\customername\print\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf,.\customer_media\customername\org\_img_print\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf)
[function.rename]: No such file or directory in  C:\www.xxx.yyy.se\admin_original_files.php on line 178
```

Since I cannot paste the whole code from **admin_original_files.php** I made a test-file and the same error occurs there.

test.php

```
<?php

$source = "\\\\gs-nkpg-raster\\RASTER_IN\\PROPRIUS\\UT-MAPP\\customername\\print\\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf";
$dest = ".\\customer_media\\customername\\org\\_img_print\\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf";

if (file_exists($source))
    echo "$source exists<br>\n";
else
    echo "$source does not exists<br>\n";

if (copy($source,$dest))
    echo "source was copied to dest<br>\n";
else
    echo "copy failed<br>\n";

if (rename($source,$dest))
    echo "source was moved to dest<br>\n";
else
    echo "move failed<br>\n";

if (unlink($source))
    echo "source was deleted<br>\n";
else
    echo "unlink source failed<br>\n";

if (unlink($dest))
    echo "dest was delete<br>\n";
else
    echo "unlink dest failed<br>\n";

?>
```

The above codes results in this:

```
\\gs-nkpg-raster\RASTER_IN\PROPRIUS\UT-MAPP\customername\print\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf exists

source was copied to dest

Warning: rename(\\gs-nkpg-raster\RASTER_IN\PROPRIUS\UT-MAPP\customername\print\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf,.\customer_media\customername\org\_img_print\GP-PP23479_Pelle_TESTee.pdf) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in C:\www.xxx.yyy.se\test.php on line 16

move failed

source was deleted

dest was delete
```

As you can see, everything except rename works. And the rename part has worked since the dawn of time until just now. Any clues?

**Edit:** I guess I should mention that I, too, believe it is a permission problem (as mentioned in the comments below). But the main question is WHY it so suddenly appears (and how to fix it, ofc). The code is at least a decade old and has worked flawlessly the last... well, 10 years.

**Edit 2:** I now learned that this problem first occurred about a month before the thunderstorm/power outage, so the server reboot seems to have nothing to do with this case.

Comment: Try adding  `getcwd()` to the start of both the paths: `getcwd() . "\\...`. The paths look a bit funky so it might take a bit a trial and error, but worth a try

Comment: Looks like a file permission error. I think that when moving files windows keeps the original file permissions. If you copy a file it will be assigned the permissions of the destination folder.

Comment: If you haven't permission you cant do it